# Bootstrap Navbar broke

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

[image: Here how it shows]

I am adding Bootstrap Navbar in React JS, but for some reason it is broke, I have Bootstrap imported in my index.html (no wrapper for React here) and I simply try the provided examples [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar&stacked=h). Not getting the same result.

```
<nav className="navbar navbar-primary Navbarstyle">
   <div class="navbar-header">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
   </div>
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
 </nav>
```

CSS

```
.Navbarstyle{
   width: 100%;
   min-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: what is '`Navbarstyle`' in your classname? Can we see the CSS of it?

Comment: Navbarstyle added

Comment: "no wrapper for React here".  In that case, you need to use "class" rather than React's "className" in your `<nav>` element

Comment: Are you loading additional `.css` files that might override one of the behavious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navbar in bootstrap is a `flex box` I got the corresponding snippet:

```
.navbar-nav {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
```

navbar-nav seems to be column orrientated, you might override it to `row`.